# Set SharingOption in ContentVersion throwing exception

Tags: contentversion

Here is my code :

```
contentV.pathOnClient='/'+contentV.Title;
contentV.SharingOption='Restricted';

try {
    insert contentV;
    List<ContentVersion> listBid =[SELECT Id, ownerId, contentDocumentId  FROM   ContentVersion WHERE Id =:contentV.Id];
    insert new ContentDocumentLink(
        linkedEntityId = bidId,
        contentDocumentId = listBid[0].contentDocumentId,
        shareType='V'
    );
}
```

It throws

> INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, Prevent others from sharing
>   and unsharing: bad value for restricted picklist field: Restricted:
>   [SharingOption]

Can anyone tell me how to update SharingOption in ContentVersion,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible values for `SharingOption` are :

1. **Label**: Freeze Sharing Off , **Value**: A
2. **Label**: Freeze Sharing On, **Value**: R

So assign `R`as a sharing option. Like :

```
 contentV.SharingOption='R';
```

Comment: does the above solution worked for you?

Comment: Yes. It is really annoying because I am not able to see the Sharing Option picklist value in Content Version.Also in document here, it said either 'Restricted' or 'Allowed'  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm . I have no idea it should be 'R' and 'A' , THANK YOU VERY MUCH